# Can I drop 4.5 V to 3.7 V with a diode?

Tags: batteries, diodes, lithium

I have an RC helicopter with a dead 250 mAh lipoly battery with a voltage of 3.7 V.
Could I use 3 button cells at 4.5 V and a diode with 0.7 voltage drop
to power the circuit, which is somewhat complex?
It has a couple of Atmel uc's and some very small BGA parts.
Or do you think it will tolerate 0.8 V difference?

Comment: Can you find out the atmel model numbers if so have a look at the datasheet.

Comment: The difference between button cells and LiPo's is extreme; the current they can deliver is just about as far apart as you can get (few milliamps for a button cell, dozens of amps for some LiPo)  Substituting one for another sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Some of the parts were deliberetly painted over

Comment: @Nick- Why not put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Nick T the heli is a bit unusual it has add on telemetry box smaller than a matchstick box which I plug in a slot in the heli this small box has the dead battery it only reads some sensors.what do you think,is that too much?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6008/use-diodes-to-obtain-lowered-dc-voltage

Comment: @Felix, so your button cell wouldn't power any motors?  Radios would be borderline, depending on power, etc.  See my answer about how the LiPo voltage can drift extremely wildly anyways.

Comment: Please, edit your question because it's unclear.

Answer (score 9):

Let me answer some basic misconceptions that you may have before going too far:

The difference between button cells and LiPo's is extreme; the current they can deliver is just about as far apart as you can get (few milliamps for a button cell, dozens of amps for some LiPo) Substituting one for another sounds like a bad idea.

Additionally, a "3.7 V" lithium-polymer battery has an enormous voltage change as it discharges, how fast, and at what temperature:

[image]
[image]

Source: http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/battery-li-poly.htm

Comment: I can't know,whitout doing to much work,how the circuit behaves.when it was new the 250mah battery lasted for 2-3 hours

Comment: @Felix: That suggests it draws about 100 mA, which most button cells can't deliver.  Some *may* be able to, but it would be at the edge of their capability, and eat your money.  Why can't you find a replacement rechargeable battery?

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up for me.I guess I'll have to order one

Comment: @NickT, @Felix. I work in button cells, You cannot easily pass 10mA with one. They suggest you do not pass 1mA.

Comment: @Kortuk, in what aspect (do you work in button cells)?

Comment: @NickT, they are the primary power source for a number of the sensor nodes used at my work. we have made and deployed over 2000 devices using them and have done extensive lifetime testing with them. Different loads, pulsed loads compared to continuous. It is interesting.

Comment: @NickT, we use other technologies, but due to their cost and our number of sensor nodes, I know button cells the best.

Answer (score 1):

As said, a li-po battery can give a huge boost in energy if required. You really don't want to short those batteries without electrical protection - they will get dangerous (i.e. explosive)

More into the diode as a solution - I've used this 'trick' once before where I had an estimation error. I had an mini servo which could work from 4.8V - 6V and my whole system designed for 6V. The batterypack I had were double packs of 5x NiMH in series. If fully charged, I got 6.7V from them. That burned a servo out quite quickly.

I dropped 2 schottky diodese in there that made a 0.6 - 0.8V drop depending on the current. Luckily my college had some diodes of >4A around, so I was able to easily hook this up. But it's not recommdend, because at low current the voltage drop may be undesired low (like 0.4V) and thus you get a too high voltage at your system.

Don't forget too that if you do with this solution and find a battery pack capable of delivering the current, you will need to dissipate that power as well. P=I*U. If I is 5A and U is 0.5V, you get a diode of 2.5W. That will make it pretty hot.